# How do I write or edit Python files?

Tags: python

When I open Python there is no file, edit, format, run, or any of the other options. It is just a blank screen with the default text.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the Python Shell from terminal, then there aren't any of those options. Running the shell gives you a blank interpreter to respond to every line of code you type instantly.

Python scripts are run by opening them in the terminal. However, you first need to write one using an IDE, a text editor, and saving as a .py file. You can then run this file by navigating to the directory in your terminal or command window.

On Mac the command would be: python myfile.py

Answer (score 0):

So, what you're probably seeing is something like this:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

As a previous answer mentioned, this is the interpreter.  You're in a mode where you type in commands and they execute immediately.  Try:

```
>>> print('Hello, World!')
Hello, World!
>>>
```

If your interpreter says `Python 2.7.x`, try:

```
>>> print 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
>>>
```

**Note:** Don't enter the `>>>`.  That's the prompt from the interpreter.

This immediately executes the command you just entered.  To write a script that you can run at any time, you put your commands into a file and run them.

If you're looking for an IDE, most Python distributions come with an IDE called IDLE.  Other people like Eclipse with PyDev.  I use Emacs with elpy.  These IDE's are more of what it sounds like you're looking for - you can enter your code, save it, edit it, and test it all from within one application.